# What is this succulent with flat hairy leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants, succulents, cactus, tropical

This succulent is about 1.5 feet tall. The leaves are flat with a white hairy type substance.

What is it called?

[image]

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post for instructions on how to [edit] an image into a post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the Kalanchoes, Kalanchoe beharensis, probably the variety 'Fang', judging by the furriness, the scalloped, brownish edges to the leaves and spiky looking protruberances beneath the leaves. Link to image here

https://toptropicals.com/pics/garden/m1/Succulent_2/Kalanchoe_beharensisFang2917.jpg

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is Cotyledon tomentosa bear's paw.

I originally forgothow I got to this conclusion. Thanks to comments below, here is my reasoning:

I grow different species of Cotyledon. I grow Cotyledon orbiculata - I have a really well grown orbiculata plant. I also have the "mint truffles" variety and a possible variety of Cotyledon "ladismenthsis" or a variance thereof. So, I started looking up Cotyledon varieties, and found a few different images references to the tomentosa bear's paw.

Comment: What points of identification make you think it is this plant?  Can you expand on the answer?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I grow different species of Cotyledon. I grow Cotyledon orbiculata - I have a really well grown orbiculata plant. I also have the "mint truffles" variety and a possible variety of Cotyledon "ladismenthsis" or a variance thereof. So, I started looking up Cotyledon varieties, and found a few different images references to the tomentosa bear's paw.

Comment: @SrihariYamanoor can you update the answer with what you put down in your comments.  That would help